# running totals when creating new excel workbooks and creating new worksheets when conditions are met

Tags: vba, excel

This is quite a long and complicated question, I will do my best to explain exactly what I need to do.

This applies to a flight department. Let's start with what I have, we use spreadsheets to track flight time, landings, and engine cycles. Currently we're using two spreadsheets, one is our "trip" sheet, and the other is our flight "log".

The trip sheet can be one to three worksheets long, it is used to track **each** flight flown during the trip. The trip could range from one flight (leg), up to 25 flights (legs), and could range from 1 day, to 21 days. Each DAY of the trip is it's own Log #, ie. if there are 3 flights on one day, they all share the same Log #. The trip #'s are not in order, one trip could be #672, the next #264543, the next #689. The creation date is the only thing that could be used to track the trip workbooks in order.

The flight log is the FAA required logbook for the aircraft. The Log #'s run in order, ie. 459, 460, 461. A flight log is required for each **day** that the aircraft flies. Some, but not all of the information from the trip sheet is required on the flight log. The most important thing is that the times, landing, and cycles calculate in order.

Now here is what I'm looking for. I'd like a spreadsheet that contains the three trip sheet worksheets as we have now, but when a flight (leg) is entered, it creates a 4th worksheet which would be the flight log. Each leg flown **that day** would have it's information transferred to that flight log. Now, when we fly on a NEW day, a 5th worksheet would be created for the new day's flight log. Times, landings, and cycle totals need to transfer over from the previous day's flight log, and the other information needed from the trip sheet just like the previous log. And so on, and so on, till the end of the TRIP.

Now here's the REAL tricky part, when we start a new TRIP, and create a new workbook for that trip, I need the totals from the previous trip to transfer to the new workbook, so a legal, running total of aircraft times can be kept.

So basically, what I want to do, is take two separate workbooks for each trip we use now, and cram them into one, but each time a new trip workbook is created I need to go grab info from the LAST workbook created to keep a running total.

New to this forum, if there's a way to attach a copy of the two workbooks we use now please tell me. Looking at what we are using would probably make a lot of this clearer.

Thank you!!! PQ

Comment: do you have the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't have one. I've used the separate workbooks, just entered everything twice, that's why I'm trying to combine the two.

Comment: There is no way to attach a document, but you can post a representative screenshot.  Unfortunately, you need more "reputation" before you gain that privilege.  And BTW, don't sweat the down-votes.  You should feel justified to ignore those that that didn't take the time to provide an accompanying reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a working solution using Excel, which is very good.  Oftentimes the biggest challenge is figuring out the process flow and all its branches.  Further it seems like you just want to make your solution more routine and sustainable to work with.

Although making a souped-up macro-enabled Excel document sounds like the right way to go, the features you are asking for are really more suited for a relational database.  Not to say it can't be done, but implementing an Excel based solution is going to be messy.  The crucial difference I believe is maintaining the the logical link between the trip sheet and the log sheet.

For example, if I understand correctly, you will have to create several Excel files, and they are going to need a naming convention in order for the computer to know which ones to look for.  This exposes the data to the most basic mishaps like mistakenly renaming or moving a file.  If you will be the only one to maintain the system, then perhaps that won't be an issue, but experience tells me that a lot of effort can be instantly undermined by something as simple as opening a file and editing it.

This also means that you will have to maintain a "builder" file that must contain the code you develop.  Not every machine is set up for macros, and a lot of end-users will get scare notices that, "this document contains macros which could be a danger...blah blah blah."  Which means every output file should probably be macro free.

Instead I would recommend recreating your system using a relational database like MS-Access.  You can create unlimited number of records/tables, and use any number of variables to maintain the logical link (by log #, by date, by flight #, etc.).  You can also set the rules so data can be recorded and reported in a consistent manner.  And if you have the need and the programming expertise, VBA macros can also be introduced to an MS-Access based solution.

Lastly, all the data could easily be kept in one central *.mdb file, which would be far easier to maintain and backup than several overlapping excel files.